What is the proper way to define polysemy as every word is a polysemy to me?
As a non-native speaker I feel every word is a polysemy because, basically, every word has several possible meanings and the context will decide its meaning in a specific sentence.
A vivid example is when I was a high school student, learned that even the simple word like zoo, can be used in the sentence like it's a complete zoo in the lobby. Or use longman example, "The grocery store was a real zoo today."

During that time I already knew cry had different meanings, like shed tears or shout, as many other words do. The word zoo just made me think that basically every word has several possible meanings.
Then I learn the word homographs, e.g. left, right, bank, study etc. But other than homographs, can I say every word is a polysemy ?
--- update ---
I am updating my question based the comments I got. My question title was not exactly right. I don't need a definition, I was frustrated or amazed (without a better word) by this linguistic phenomenon that English has so many polysemy, to a level that I feel almost every word is a polysemy. It has always been a big hurdle for my learning.
The wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy is a good read, e.g. I learn that "the three most polysemous words in English are run, put, and set, in that order."  The word run is a very good example shows my frustration. In Chinese run just means run, the movement. So I have a hard time learning the word run in English.
But that wiki also partially answers my question that there are different types of polysemy, linear polysemy and non-linear polysemy.

The definition of zoo as 'a situation characterized by confusion and disorder' is not really a different meaning, just an extension of the 'real' meaning as a metaphor. I'm not familiar with the expression myself, but presumably it comes from the idea of a zoo being full of wild animals.

So zoo may not be a good example for you. But I think my question remains. Every English word to me is basically polysemy.

Have you read this article?

I don't know if this belongs on Linguistics SE. Every language has polysemy: Chinese, French, Navajo, etc. It's also a matter of opinion how you count different meanings. But common, short words are more likely to be polysemous, in English as probably in any other language.

I've voted to close because questions about the proper way to define a technical term are matters of debate and opinion, which are off-topic here.  One could debate whether  figurative uses should be treated as a different meaning.

@StuartF it is true every language has polysemy but my question is every English word is  a polysemy (to me). This is definitely NOT the case in Chinese.

You can use adjectives/participles, and nouns as metaphors and similes. "I'm frazzled, traffic was a jungle out there“, "It's like living in a mad house", "The sea was as flat as a board”... words can be used for exaggeration and can change from a noun to a verb: “Literally every noun can be turned into a verb. For example to ‘to science it out’

@Mari-LouA then what is your take on my question ?

@TimR I understand your point. But how do you explain that every word in English dictionary all has several items, i.e. had different meanings. If they are not polysemy, what are they? BTW, it is always one of biggest hurdles for my English learning.

That you feel every word in the English is polysemous because you witness how flexible English is. When in actual fact the core meanings of "zoo", "frazzle", "jungle",  "board" and "science" are maintained. The word polysemy itself  has only one meaning, as far as I know, but it doesn't mean it can't be manipulated or modified in the future.

@Mari-LouA yes polysemy has one meaning, so I said basically. Monosemy is another big word I learn today and I dare to say English has far less monosemy than say Chinese.

"basically" means "on the whole" in your sentence “…because, basically, every word has several possible meanings”. Does that mean you are aware that some words in the English language have a single meaning, then why are you asking if there's a word that defines polysemy? Polysemy is the word you are looking for.

@KateBunting thanks for the article. So now I learn "the three most polysemous words in English are run, put, and set, in that order" and the concept of non-linear polysemy.

@Qiulang邱朗  Why do you need a name for the phenomenon?  Why can't you say "English words can have more than one meaning, although usually the syntax of the sentence combined with the context will make clear which meaning is intended."  ?

@TimR that is not my question. I don't need a name. I was confused or amazed (without finding a better word) to find almost every word in English is a polysemy. As I said in other comments. Compared to Chinese that is a very different linguistic phenomenon, Chinese has far less polysemy in my opinion. And that is one of obstacles when I learn English.

If you are talking about the orthographic / typographic representation of words: an English word on the page is, in the overwhelming majority of cases, a representation, using the Latin alphabet, of the sounds of a word as it was spoken some centuries ago. In many instances the present-day pronunciation is quite close to older pronunciations and in many instances quite different.  There have been attempts to normalize spelling over the centuries. In pre-Conquest Old English there were dozens of ways to spell the word for "sister", for example, reflecting local dialect pronunciations.

You will find nouns that consist of  the same sounds as a verb in a particular declension, and their spelling representations will be identical, noun and verb, even though the meaning is wildly different. "a can of tuna" versus "Can you call my phone?" But as I wrote above, syntax and context usually are enough to disambiguate.  So for some learners, learning to read English is a syntax-first process.

I think it feels this way because the words we deal with most as learners are the most common ones, and those are the words that are asked to do the most work. Many technical words are very specific. "Sodium chloride" means nothing but table salt; "hex nut" means a certain hexagonal piece of hardware. (Yes these are phrases, but that's not really important when dealing with meaning; I could have said "argon" etc.) It can be frustrating to try to "memorize the dictionary," taking a word and trying to know all the things it can mean. Less frustrating is to start with meanings and then assign...

... idiomatic expressions to them. Along the way you discover polysemy ("Oh, I use 'run' to mean 'operate this machine' as well as when running on foot"), but mentally we're attaching words and phrases to meanings rather than the other way around.

I’m voting to close this question because it never had a very answerable question, and especially after editing seems to be just an expression of frustration without an answerable question.

This is definitely the case in Chinese.  You deal with the multiple meanings in Chinese without worrying about it, without even noticing it.  This is because you define "meaning" to be "the word in Chinese" and note words with multiple meanings in English as "have several translations"... But please trust me Chinese is just like English.  Chinese words have multiple meanings. Just like English.  And you deal with it the same way that you do in Chinese.

@JamesK Well, I am Chinese and I can tell you "run" in Chinese just mean the movement with your foot without other meaning. You combine run with other Chinese Character to form other meanings, but that is a different story.  The answer I got from Astralbee said " in his book The Stuff of Thought suggests that most words in English are polysemous." and it is good to know.

@AndyBonner my editing indeed seems to make the question hard to answer, but the basic question is "other than homographs, can I say every word is a polysemy" and the answer I got said "in his book The Stuff of Thought suggests that most words in English are polysemous.". So I am satisfied to see other shared this view. I also learned that I probably shouldn't count metaphor as a form of being polysemous.

I can totally promise you that you are wrong about your language.  You are wrong even in this particular case: "我不知道我的眼镜跑哪儿去了"  or do glasses have feet?

Your example of the word 'zoo' used to refer to a busy grocery store is not an example of polysemy - that is an example of a metaphor. Polysemy means that a single word has multiple meanings or senses. You should expect those meanings to be defined in a dictionary, and context may determine how to read that word. When you use a word or phrase as a metaphor it is deliberately out of context.
A widely cited source on the prevalence of polysemy is linguist Steven Pinker, who in his book The Stuff of Thought suggests that most words in English are polysemous. The figure is typically estimated to be around 40-60%. Having established that metaphorical use is not proof of polysemy, it's not hard to think of words that only have one literal meaning. Photosynthesis, for example.
Also, just an aside, but 'polysemy' is the noun for the phenomenon of a word having multiple meanings, not for the word itself. A polysemous word is a polyseme.

It feels good to read that "who in his book The Stuff of Thought suggests that most words in English are polysemous".
